# Running grunt with mochaProtractor specifying dependancies?? chai assertion library?

Tags: gruntjs, mocha.js, specifications, protractor

I've set up a gruntfile that looks like the following. The aim being to perform e2e tests using protractor for my angularjs project. When running this using mochaProtractor Chrome fires up as expect but the lint is telling me that I'm missing the dependancies for the expect statement. This should referencing the assertion library chai. How do I include dependencies for chai to get this to work correctly?

Thanks

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
      scripts: {
        files: ['public/specs/e2e/*.js'],
        tasks: ['mochaProtractor','jshint'],
        options: {
          spawn: false,
        },
      },
    },
    jshint: {
      all: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        'public/app/js/*.js'
      ],
      options: {
        curly: true,
        eqeqeq: true,
        immed: true,
        latedef: true,
        newcap: true,
        noarg: true,
        sub: true,
        undef: true,
        unused: true,
        boss: true,
        eqnull: true,
        node: true
      }
    },
    mochaProtractor: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['Chrome']
      },
      files: ['public/specs/e2e/*.js'],
      baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/'
    },
  });

  // These plugins provide necessary tasks.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-protractor');
```

Below is the spec I'm trying to test against. Note: I added the require statement at the top in attempt to get it to work. Any thoughts?

```
var chai = require('chai');

var expect = chai.expect;

describe("Given a task entry screen", function() {
        ptor = protractor.getInstance();

      beforeEach(function() {
        ptor.get('#/');
        button = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.className('btn-say-hello'));
        button.click();
      });

      it('says hello', function() {
        message = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.className('message'));
        expect(message.getText()).toEqual('Hello!');
      });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add chai as a dev dependency in your `package.json`.

```
{
  "name": "yourProject",
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "~1.8.1"
  }
}
```

then install the dependenvy via

```
npm install`
```

and then you should be able to write a spec :

```
var chai = require('chai');

var expect = chai.expect;

describe("Given a task entry screen", function() {
        ptor = protractor.getInstance();

      beforeEach(function() {
        ptor.get('#/');
        button = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.className('btn-say-hello'));
        button.click();
      });

      it('says hello', function() {
        message = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.className('message'));
        expect(message.getText()).toEqual('Hello!');
      });


});
```